# Can't print special character in php

Tags: php, linux

I'm trying to concatenate the grater then caracter ">" to a string

I'm using the code but the output looks different as i want,

```
<?php
$target_file="home.txt"
$caract = htmlspecialchars(">");
$command = escapeshellcmd('sudo python test.py '.$target_file.$caract.' out.txt');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $command;
?>
```

also i tried the "&gt" but it gives the same results

here is the output of echo $command; how it is:

```
sudo python test.py home.txt \>\; out.txt
```

and i want it like that :

```
sudo python test.py home.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: Don't pack the `>` sign into `escapeshellcmd`, the function exactly does what it should do, *escape*.

Comment: You don't generate HTML in the code you posted. Why do you use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)?

Comment: Building on what Charlotte said you should use `escapeshellarg` on the filename only, so like this `'sudo python test.py '.escapeshellarg( $target_file ).' > out.txt'`  There is no need to escape text literals only input variables.

Comment: It's weird that today a `Build on what Charlotte said` trend started... @ArtisticPhoenix

Answer (score 1):

Usually you should call escapeshellcmd if you use user's input as part of the executing command. If you don't do you should simply call shell_exec(command);

```
shell_exec('sudo python test.py ' . $target_file . ' > out.txt');
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `htmlspecialchars()` as `shell_exec` does not understand HTML.

You should just use the code provided by @ArtisticPhoenix: `shell_exec('sudo python test.py '.escapeshellarg( $target_file ).' > out.txt');` Hope this helps!